# How to assign different data types to 2 dimension vba array

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, sumproduct

this is a vba related question:
I have created a 2 dimension array (option base 0) in which I have loaded dates into column zero (row 0 to 8), and percentages in column one (row 0 to 8). I have Dim-ed the array As Variant. My problem is I would like to now loop through column=1 and do the product of the sum of (1+ % value in array), but I am getting an error: Run-time error 13 Type mismatch. I think it is because the % values in my array have " " quotations around them and are not assigned a numerical data type. Would anyone know how I can make sure percentages% in my array can directly be used in mathematical operations (e.g. 1 + array value)? In other words, make sure the dates are treated like dates, and the percentages% are treated like numbers?

```
'Create array
Dim myReturnsArray() As Variant
'Redim array
ReDim myReturnsArray(numberPeriods, 1)

'Bunch of code to load dates in column 0, load percentages in column 1

'Check the final dimensions of our return array
RowCount = UBound(myReturnsArray, 1)
ColCount = UBound(myReturnsArray, 2)

'set counter to 1
cummulativeRet = 1
'loop through the column 1 of my array and do the sum product of the percentage values it holds
For twocounter = 0 To RowCount
'Run time error: type mismatch, it wont let me do a mathematical operation directly on the value in 
the array!!! HELP!
cummulativeRet = cummulativeRet * (1 + myReturnsArray(twocounter, 1))
Next
```

Comment: load percentages as e.g. 0.1

Comment: @QHarr it worked! Thank you very much :) Happy holidays as well.

Comment: you are most welcome